# change data structure of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this sample data...

```
import pandas as pd

from StringIO import StringIO

stock_list="""EAN code, name, stock
, MONIN Syrups,
12345, Monin Mojito Mint Syrup 250 ml, 100
, BONNE MAMAN,
7890. Bonne Maman Strawberry Preserve 370g, 200
6543, Bonne Maman Raspberry 370g, 150"""

audit = pd.read_csv(StringIO(stock_list), sep="," )
```

If the EAN code is "Not A Number" then it is actually the product type. So the product name "MONIN syrups" should be moved to type column for the following products till the next NaN.
The final list will look something like this...

```
expected_list="""type,  EAN code,   name,   stock
MONIN Syrups,   12345,  Monin Mojito Mint Syrup 250 ml, 100
BONNE MAMAN,    7890,   Bonne Maman Strawberry Preserve 370g,   200
BONNE MAMAN,    6543,   Bonne Maman Raspberry 370g, 150"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(expected_list), sep="," )
```

How do I take the current "stock_list" dataframe and change it such a way that it will look like expected_list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `name` column to `type` column, clear elements to NaN and `ffill()` it:

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

stock_list="""EAN code, name, stock
, MONIN Syrups,
12345, Monin Mojito Mint Syrup 250 ml, 100
, BONNE MAMAN,
7890, Bonne Maman Strawberry Preserve 370g, 200
6543, Bonne Maman Raspberry 370g, 150"""


audit = pd.read_csv(StringIO(stock_list), sep=",", skipinitialspace=True)


audit["type"] = audit["name"]

mask = ~audit["EAN code"].isnull()
audit.loc[mask, "type"] = np.nan
audit["type"].ffill(inplace=True)
res = audit.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
```

output:

```
   EAN code                                  name  stock          type
0   12345.0        Monin Mojito Mint Syrup 250 ml  100.0  MONIN Syrups
1    7890.0  Bonne Maman Strawberry Preserve 370g  200.0   BONNE MAMAN
2    6543.0            Bonne Maman Raspberry 370g  150.0   BONNE MAMAN
```